# Sigma additivity of spectral measure on the complex Borel-sigma algebra

Tags: functional-analysis

My exact question is asked and answered here:

[Proving that a spectral measure is $\sigma$-additive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146041/proving-that-a-spectral-measure-is-sigma-additive)

but I have spent all day trying to construct the $A^{'}_js$ and $B^{'}_k$s described in the answer and haven't succeeded. I know A und B must each be elements of the Borel-sigma Algebra on $\mathbb{R} \ 
 (\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$) because the Borel-sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R^2}$ is the cartesian product of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with itself, $$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2}) =  \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$  and because of sigma-algebra qualities, the union over $A_i \times B_i$ must be contained in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})$, but I don't know exactly what A and B look like, and maybe that's my problem. I would really appreciate some help constructing the $A^{'}_js$ and $B^{'}_k$s.

Comment: Ignore what's said in the answer to the post you linked to, and instead read chapter 11 on amalgamation of Berberian's notes [here](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/09/09-32.pdf).  It's more general in that it deals with positive-operator valued measures, not just projection-valued measures - but at least it's done carefully.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!